Examining whether the relation "$aRb$ iff $a + 2b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$" is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive
Have I shown correctly which properties the relation fulfills?
$$aRb \text{ iff } a + 2b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

$(1)$ Reflexivity
Set $b=a$
$a + 2a = 3a \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
Hence, the relation is reflexive.

$(2)$ Symmetry
(*) $a + 2b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
(**) $b + 2a \equiv 0  \pmod 3$
Assuming (*) and (**) are true, the sum must also be divisible by three (if * and ** were not satisfied, the sum would lie in another congruence class):
$a + b + 2a + 2b = (a+b) + 2(a+b) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
Set $a+b=c$
Then $c + 2c = 3c \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
Hence, the relation is symmetric.

$(3)$ Antisymmetry
Counterexample: $a=4, b = -5$
$4 + 2*(-5)=-6 \equiv 0 \pmod 3\implies aRb$
$-5 + 2*4 = 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3\implies bRa$
But $a\neq b$, hence the relation is not antisymmetric.

$(4)$ Transitivity
$a + 2b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
$b + 2c \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
$a + b + 2(b+c) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
$(a + 2b) + b + 2 c \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
Hence, $(a+2c)\equiv0 \pmod 3 \implies $ relation is transitive.

This is all made much easier by reformulating the relation:
$$
a + 2b \equiv 0\pmod 3 \iff\
a + (-1)b \equiv 0\pmod 3 \iff\
a - b \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \iff\
a \equiv b \pmod 3
$$

Your proof of symmetry makes no sense. The other proofs are fine, and you are correct about which properties the relation fulfills.

Solution vertification requires that you be specific on which step you are unclear of. We are not a proof-checking site.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

$!\bmod 3!:\ a+2b\equiv 0\iff a\equiv -2b\equiv b.,$ But $,aRb ,:=, a\equiv b\pmod{!3},$ is an equivalence relation by the linked dupe.

The symmetry proof is nonsense. You're assuming that $aRb$ and $bRa$ to be true at the outset, and reach an unclear conclusion.
The definition of symmetry is: if $aRb$ is true, then $bRa$ is also true.
For example:

$xRy$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ is true when $|x-y|=1$
$xRy$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is true when $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$
$xRy$ for $x,y$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is true when $x \parallel y$

These are symmetric relations. For instance,
$$
1 = |x-y| = |(-1)(y-x)| = |-1| \cdot |y-x| = |y-x|
$$
Thus, you start out by only assuming that $aRb$ holds, and from that alone you need to show that $bRa$ holds.

For the transitivity proof, you reach the right conclusion, but I don't think you understand what you're doing based on the equations written.
So, we know that $aRb$ and $bRc$ are true, and we seek to prove that $aRc$ is true. Since $aRb$ and $bRc$, then
$$\begin{align*}
a + 2b &\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
b + 2c &\equiv 0 \pmod 3
\end{align*}$$
The natural way forward, to proving that
$$
a + 2c \equiv 0 \pmod 3
$$
is to add the two equations we know to be true. This gives us
$$
a+2b+b+2c \equiv 0 \pmod 3
$$
But this is the same as
$$
a+2c+3b \equiv 0 \pmod 3
$$
Since, presumably, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $3b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ always, leaving us with
$$
a+2c \equiv 0 \pmod 3
$$
and hence $aRc$ as desired.

The other two items are fine and I see no prominent issues with them.

Please do not answer off-topic questions (SV missing required context).

AND you answered a duplicate. Please use due diligence, and search for similar questions already answered, rather than rushing to answer.
